# Applying a function to multiple rows of a time series in R

Tags: r, xts

I have a time series with multiple columns, some have `NA`s in them, for example:

```
date.a<-seq(as.Date('2014-01-01'),as.Date('2014-02-01'),by = 2)
date.b<-seq(as.Date('2014-01-01'),as.Date('2014-02-15'),by = 3)
df.a <- data.frame(time=date.a, A=sin((1:16)*pi/8))
df.b <- data.frame(time=date.b, B=cos((1:16)*pi/8))
my.ts <- merge(xts(df.a$A,df.a$time),xts(df.b$B,df.b$time))
```

I'd like to apply a function to each of the rows, in particular:

```
prices2percreturns <- function(x){100*diff(x)/x}
```

I think that `sapply` should do the trick, but

```
sapply(my.ts, prices2percreturns)
```

gives `Error in array(r, dim = d, dimnames = if (!(is.null(n1 <- names(x[[1L]])) &  : 
  length of 'dimnames' [1] not equal to array extent`.  I suspect that this is due to the `NA`s when merging, but maybe I'm just doing something wrong. Do I need to remove the `NA`s or is there something wrong with the length of the vector returned by the function?

Comment: Are you just trying to do this: `100*diff(my.ts)/my.ts`? Calling `diff` on a single row wouldn't make sense.  Also, `sapply` will apply the function to each column.  `apply(my.ts, 1, FUN)` would apply a function to each row, but is probably not what you want here.

Comment: Yes. Consider posting this as an answer.

Comment: Consider looking at `TTR::ROC` and `quantmod::Delt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the comments, you don't actually want to apply the function to each row.  Instead you want to leverage the vectorized nature of R.  i.e. you can simply do this

```
100*diff(my.ts)/my.ts
```

If you do want to apply a function to each row of a matrix (which is what an xts object is), you can use `apply` with `MARGIN=1`.  i.e.  `apply(my.ts, 1, myFUN)`.

`sapply(my.ts, myFUN)` would work like `apply(my.ts, 2, myFUN)` in this case -- applying a function to each column.

Comment: I think your suggested solution is basing the returns on the period end values and not the values at the beginning of the period as  Hans pointed out, therefore the term should be divided by the lagged values of my.ts like so :`100*diff(my.ts)/lag(my.ts)`

Comment: @hvollmeier. True, I'm copying the OP because he provided a specific calculation, but didn't actually say he was calculating returns.  Hopefully the OP will look at the source of the functions I recommended in the comment above.

Answer (score 1):

Your `diff(x)` will be 1 shorter than your `x`. Also your returns will be based on the results. You want returns based on the starting price not the end price. Here I change the function to reflect that and apply the function per column.

```
prices2percreturns <- function(x){100*diff(x)/x[-length(x)]}
prcRets = apply(my.ts, 2, prices2percreturns)
```

Comment: actually `diff.xts` will be dispatched, and it will return an `xts` of the same number of rows as the input, padding the first row with `NA` (by default)